# Toggle up all elements if were open

Tags: javascript, jquery

For this markup:

```
<div id="citate">Citate</div>
<div id="unu" hidden>Autori</div>
<div id="autori" hidden>
    <ul>
        <li>Ion Creanga</li>
        <li>Ion Creanga</li>
        <li>Ion Creanga</li>
        <li>Ion Creanga</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="doi" hidden>Subiecte</div>
<div id="subiecte" hidden>
    <ul>
        <li>Creanga</li>
        <li>Creanga</li>
        <li>Creanga</li>
        <li>Creanga</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have this code [JS](http://jsfiddle.net/eZan6/) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div#citate").click(function () {
        $("div#unu ").slideToggle();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div#citate").click(function () {
        $("div#doi ").slideToggle();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div#unu").click(function () {
        $("div#autori").slideToggle();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div#doi").click(function () {
        $("div#subiecte").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

and i want when i click second time on "Citate" it will toogleup all other elements from toogledown "Autori" and "Subiecte" if there were open. I try to do it, I searched how to but can not do it right.
I used `slideToggle()` function.

Comment: What you want to do...Explain more! On second click it gets toggleUp on my side...

Comment: Yes but try toggle the others two and than toogle up "Citate"

Comment: Part of Stack Overflow's objective is to provide a searchable database of problems and their solutions. The jsFiddle link is nice, but please provide at least part of your code (preferably the parts that are relevant to your issue), here, so that others who might run into the same problem can learn as solutions are offered.

Comment: Actually did it for you, just this time. (I forgot that I have more edit privileges than before.)

Comment: @mori57 I was going to edit that but you did it faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This can help you.**

```
$("div#citate").click(function(){
   if(  $('div#autori, div#subiecte').is(':visible') ){
      $("div#unu, div#doi,div#autori, div#subiecte").slideUp();
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eZan6/5/)

No need to add $(document).ready again and agian

Comment: This is what i was expecting to get.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Its Working` use callback : [See DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/eZan6/4/)

Answer (score 0):

[This is not a optimal solution](http://jsfiddle.net/eZan6/6/) as it does not scale at all, but it works. If you toggle the parent (`#citate`) and your submenus are `visible`, then close them by using `slideToggle` or `slideUp`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("div#citate").click(function(){
      $("div#unu").slideToggle();
      $("div#doi").slideToggle();
      if($("div#autori").is(":visible")) {
        $("div#autori").slideToggle();
      }
      if($("div#subiecte").is(":visible")) {
        $("div#subiecte").slideToggle();
      }
  });

  $("div#unu").click(function(){
      $("div#autori").slideToggle();
  });

  $("div#doi").click(function(){
      $("div#subiecte").slideToggle();
  });
});
```